# Need to use function console.log only once

Tags: javascript, function

I want to create a small program that will count a discounted price. 
The task is to use the `console.log` function only once. 
In case the input price will be negative (ex. -40), `console log` need to show "Invalid input"

My program counts discount in both variants - when the price is positive and when the price is negative.

Please, help me to find a mistake. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```js
const price = prompt('Please, enter the price:');
const discount = prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:');

function discountPrice(price, discount) {
  if ((price && discount) > 0) {
    return price - price * discount / 100
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid data')
  }
}

let newPrice = discountPrice(price, discount)
let savedMoney = price - newPrice

console.log(
  'New price is:', newPrice, '\n' +
  'Price without discount:', price, '\n' +
  'Discount:', discount, '%', '\n' +
  'Price with discount:', newPrice, '\n' +
  'Saved:', savedMoney);
```

Comment: As @Teemu said, first of all you should work with Numbers, not strings (although in this case it just happens to work). Use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert. Also, what does `(price && discount) > 0`  mean?

Comment: Price and discount are positive numbers 

You mean newPrice = parseInt(discountPrice(price, discount)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
if ((price && discount) > 0) {
```

probably doesn't do what you're expecting - for example, if `price` is negative but `discount` is positive, it'll evaluate to `true` anyway, which is not what you want if you want to check whether *both* are greater than zero, you might check whether `every` item of an array of `[price, discount]` is greater than 0.

```
[price, discount].every(num => num > 0)
```

To indicate an invalid return value, you might return `null`. Then, assign the text string to print based on that return value. Use the conditional operator and template literals to reduce syntax noise:

```js
const price = prompt('Please, enter the price:');
const discount = prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:');

function discountPrice(price, discount) {
  return [price, discount].every(num => num > 0)
  ? price - price * discount / 100
  : null
}

const newPrice = discountPrice(price, discount);
const savedMoney = price - newPrice;

const textToPrint = newPrice === null
? 'Invalid Data'
: `New price is: ${newPrice}
Price without discount: ${price}
Discount: ${discount}%'
Price with discount:: ${newPrice}
Saved: ${savedMoney}
`;

console.log(textToPrint);
```

Comment: can you explain what this const mean?

const textToPrint = newPrice === null

Comment: That's the conditional operator. If `newPrice` is `null`, `textToPrint` resolves to `Invalid Data`, else it resolves to the long template literal string.

Comment: thank you for explanation!

I want to rewrite this part to if else format:

{
  return [price, discount].every(num => num > 0)
  ? price - price * discount / 100
  : null

Comment: it will be:

if ((price > 0) && (discount > 0)) {
discount price  = price - price * discount / 100
} else {
discount price = null
}
is that correct?

Comment: Sure, you can do that too for the `if` statement, but `discount price = ...` is invalid syntax.

Comment: I mean
`if ((price > 0) && (discount > 0)) { 
discountPrice = price - price * discount / 100
 } else { discountPrice = null }`

now it is correct?

Comment: `discountPrice` is the name of the function - you shouldn't reassign the function to a string. Instead, better to `return` the result so you can assign it to the desired variable outside when calling the function

Answer (score 0):

```js
const price = prompt('Please, enter the price:');
const discount = prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:');

function discountPrice(price, discount) {
  if (price < 0 || discount <  0) {
    console.log('Invalid data')
    return false
  } else {
    return price - price * discount / 100
    
  }
}

let newPrice = discountPrice(price, discount)
if(newPrice){
let savedMoney = price - newPrice

console.log(
  'New price is:', newPrice, '\n' +
  'Price without discount:', price, '\n' +
  'Discount:', discount, '%', '\n' +
  'Price with discount:', newPrice, '\n' +
  'Saved:', savedMoney);
}
```

Comment: result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a `if-else` logic something like this which will work for both `price` and `discount` to check if they are negative values or not.

```js
const price = prompt('Please, enter the price:');
const discount = prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:');

function discountPrice(price, discount) {
  if (price <= 0 || discount <= 0) {
    return 'Invalid data';
  }
  if (price && discount) {
    let newPrice = price - price * discount / 100;
    let savedMoney = price - newPrice;
    return 'New price is: ' + newPrice +', \n' +
    'Price without discount: '+ price +', \n' +
    'Discount: '+ discount +', '%', \n' +
    'Price with discount: '+ newPrice+ ', \n' +
    'Saved: ' + savedMoney;
  }
}

let newPrice = discountPrice(price, discount);
console.log(newPrice);
```

Comment: the challenge is how to use console.log only one time

Comment: @John it console log only one time. Isn;t that what you need?

Comment: I mean I need to use console.log function only 1 time in my program

Comment: @John you could have ticked that because this was simple to use and understand than the one you ticked

Comment: by the way, what do you mean by 
"if (price && discount)"?
should it be like "if ((price > 0) && (discount > 0))"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178113/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

> Correct your discountPrice function

```
function discountPrice(price, discount) {
  if (price > 0 && discount> 0) {    //         <<--- Here    
    return price - price * discount / 100
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid data')
  }
}
```

This is not English. This is JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the if condition as below,

```
if ( price > 0 && discount > 0 ) {
    return price - price * discount / 100
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid data')
  }
```

Also add the below if condition with the final console.log in your code,

```
if (newPrice){
        console.log(
          'New price is:', newPrice, '\n' +
          'Price without discount:', price, '\n' +
          'Discount:', discount, '%', '\n' +
          'Price with discount:', newPrice, '\n' +
          'Saved:', savedMoney);
        }
```

So the modified code will be,

```js
    const price = prompt('Please, enter the price:');
    const discount = prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:');
    
    function discountPrice(price, discount) {
      if ( price > 0 && discount > 0 ) {
        return price - price * discount / 100
      } else {
        console.log('Invalid data')
      }
    }
    
    let newPrice = discountPrice(price, discount)
    let savedMoney = price - newPrice
    if (newPrice){
    console.log(
      'New price is:', newPrice, '\n' +
      'Price without discount:', price, '\n' +
      'Discount:', discount, '%', '\n' +
      'Price with discount:', newPrice, '\n' +
      'Saved:', savedMoney);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you always will logged the last message to your console, you should put a `condition` to check before you `console.log` it.

You have To check the returned value of the `discountPrice` function.
if it is a number then `console.log` your message, else you shouldn't.

Also you have to change the if condition to be `if ((price - discount) > 0)`
 instead of `if ((price && discount) > 0)`

```js
const price = prompt('Please, enter the price:');
const discount = prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:');

function discountPrice(price, discount) {
  if ((price - discount) > 0) {
    return price - price * discount / 100
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid data')
  }
}

let newPrice = discountPrice(price, discount)
let savedMoney = price - newPrice

if(!isNaN(newPrice)){
console.log(
  'New price is:', newPrice, '\n' +
  'Price without discount:', price, '\n' +
  'Discount:', discount, '%', '\n' +
  'Price with discount:', newPrice, '\n' +
  'Saved:', savedMoney);
}
```

---

You can also change your code to be like this.

```js
const price = prompt('Please, enter the price:');
const discount = prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:');

if ((price - discount) > 0) {
  let newPrice =  price - price * discount / 100;
  let savedMoney = price - newPrice;
  console.log(
  'New price is:', newPrice, '\n' +
  'Price without discount:', price, '\n' +
  'Discount:', discount, '%', '\n' +
  'Price with discount:', newPrice, '\n' +
  'Saved:', savedMoney);
} else {
  console.log('Invalid data')
}
```